# Hibernate hbm and POJOs from DB doesn't generate foreign keys names

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new of hibernate and I generated POJOs form DB using a Netbeans sample project. All seems work correctly but in the hbn and java file there are no foreign key names, this is a problem because I would like generate schema DDL starting from POJOs files

My hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1:1521:orcl</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">TABLE_OWN</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">TABLE_OWN</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.reveng.xml

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-schema="TAB_OWN"/>
  <table-filter match-name="TABLE1"/>
  <table-filter match-name="TABLE2"/>
  <table-filter match-name="TABLE3"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

the original DDL

```
CREATE TABLE BJADRE
(
   RE_ADID varchar(14) NOT NULL,
   RE_ADID_SEQ varchar(2) NOT NULL,
   RE_ADSTAT varchar(1) NOT NULL,
   RE_ADFROM varchar(6) NOT NULL,
   RE_ADOPNO decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
   RE_JSNAME varchar(16) DEFAULT ' '  NOT NULL,
   RE_REOPNO decimal(22,0) DEFAULT 0  NOT NULL,
   RE_COMPL varchar(1) DEFAULT ' '  NOT NULL,
   RE_JOBNAME varchar(40) DEFAULT ' '  NOT NULL,
   RE_JSWS varchar(16) DEFAULT ' '  NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (RE_ADID,RE_ADID_SEQ,RE_ADSTAT,RE_ADFROM,RE_ADOPNO)
)
ENGINE INNODB COLLATE=latin1_general_cs;
--
ALTER TABLE BJADRE
ADD CONSTRAINT BJADRE_FRE01
FOREIGN KEY
(
  RE_ADID,
  RE_ADID_SEQ,
  RE_ADSTAT,
  RE_ADFROM,
  RE_ADOPNO
)
REFERENCES BJADOP
(
  OP_ADID,
  OP_ADID_SEQ,
  OP_ADSTAT,
  OP_ADFROM,
  OP_ADOPNO
) ON DELETE CASCADE
;
```

the hbm file generated by hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 18-feb-2016 10.16.35 by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.a.b.tables.Bjadre" table="BJADRE">
        <composite-id name="id" class="com.a.b.tables.BjadreId">
            <key-property name="reAdid" type="string">
                <column name="RE_ADID" length="14" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="reAdidSeq" type="string">
                <column name="RE_ADID_SEQ" length="2" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="reAdstat" type="string">
                <column name="RE_ADSTAT" length="1" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="reAdfrom" type="string">
                <column name="RE_ADFROM" length="6" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="reAdopno" type="big_decimal">
                <column name="RE_ADOPNO" precision="22" scale="0" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <one-to-one name="bjadop" class="com.a.b.tables.Bjadop" constrained="true"></one-to-one>
        <property name="reJsname" type="string">
            <column name="RE_JSNAME" length="16" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="reReopno" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="RE_REOPNO" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="reCompl" type="string">
            <column name="RE_COMPL" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="reJobname" type="string">
            <column name="RE_JOBNAME" length="40" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="reJsws" type="string">
            <column name="RE_JSWS" length="16" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

in the hbn there are non reference to foreign key name BJADRE_FRE01
hibernate generates the following foreign key named FK74D139DE74DBF99B

```
alter table JADE_OWN.JADE_OWN.BJADRE add index FK74D139DE74DBF99B (RE_ADID, RE_ADID_SEQ, RE_ADSTAT, RE_ADFROM, RE_ADOPNO), add constraint FK74D139DE74DBF99B foreign key (RE_ADID, RE_ADID_SEQ, RE_ADSTAT, RE_ADFROM, RE_ADOPNO) references JADE_OWN.JADE_OWN.BJADOP (OP_ADID, OP_ADID_SEQ, OP_ADSTAT, OP_ADFROM, OP_ADOPNO)
```

thanks

Comment: Do you need specify a column name with a foreign key or a name of constraint?

Comment: the name of costraints. in the file hbm I have the definition of foreign key but no info about name, see the many-to-one tag         <many-to-one name="bjadcom" class="com.res.jade.tables.Bjadcom" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="OP_ADID" length="14" not-null="true" />
            <column name="OP_ADID_SEQ" length="2" not-null="true" />
            <column name="OP_ADSTAT" length="1" not-null="true" />
            <column name="OP_ADFROM" length="6" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

Comment: For an example, `alter table users_roles  add constraint some_constraint_name  foreign key (role_id)  references spring_roles (f_id)` you need the ability to specify `some_constraint_name`?

Comment: Please, add all examples to the question, not to comments.

Comment: post updated with more details